# Viewing all functions in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I know I can use Alt+7 to view Structure using Intellij but that only shows me the root main `def` but how can I view all of my functions I have defined inside my main also? Want to be able to jump around quickly to different functions within a file. But it does work if I use `object <objectName> extends App` instead of `def main(args: Array[String])`

Comment: the 'search' everywhere function is not sufficient ?

Comment: but that requires that I already know a name to search for. I was hoping for something that just quickly shows a list of all of the functions in the file as  "sub-functions" defined inside `def main(args: Array[String]) {` for example.

Comment: I've no idea about scala but in Java it's ctrl-F12.